# in TensorFlow 2.0, what is the different between LSTM and LSTMCell objects?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, rnn

I am trying to implement an RNN in TensorFlow 2.0 (beta1). Looking at the layer functions (inherited from Keras) I found:

```
tf.keras.layers.LSTM
```

and

```
tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell
```

What is the different between the two? If you take a look at their arguments, they seem the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right - the difference is minimal. The base LSTMCell class implements the main functionality required, such as the [`build`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.0.0-beta1/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L2136) method, whereas the LSTM class only container an entry point: the [`call`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.0.0-beta1/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L2529) method, as well as a bunch of *getters* to retrieve attribute values. [**LSTMCell**](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.0.0-beta1/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L2028) is the base class, which is used as a [**cell**](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.0.0-beta1/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L2500) that is used inside the [**LSTM**](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.0.0-beta1/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L2381) class.

All links point to relevant parts of `tensorflow.keras` source code.

My advice would be to use the standard LSTM class in your model as a normal layer. If you have a GPU at your disposal, you might want to use the version of the layer that is optimised with CUDA for execution on a GPU. As per the documentation:

> Note that this cell is not optimized for performance on GPU. Please use
>     `tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM` for better performance on GPU.

There is also a `GRU` layer as well as a `CuDNNGRU` layer.

---

If you want to tweak how things work under the hood, you might create a class and inherit from the LSTMCell, or even the base class:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer import Layer

class MyLSTM(Layer):
    pass
```

But you would have to implement many things for yourself.