# RNN in pseudo-code

Tags: neural-network, lstm, rnn, implementation

A few years ago, I understood the classical MLP neural network much better when I wrote an  implementation from scratch (using only Python + Numpy, without using tensorflow). Now I'd like to do the same for recurrent neural networks.

For a standard MLP NN with dense layers, the forward-propagation can be summarized by:

```
def predict(x0):
    x = x0
    for i in range(numlayers-1):
        y = dot(W[i], x) + B[i]     # W[i] is a weight matrix, B[i] the biases 
        x = activation[i](y)
    return x
```

**For a given single layer**, the idea is just:

```
output_vector = activation(W[i] * input_vector + B[i])
```

**What's the equivalent for a simple RNN layer, eg. [`SimpleRNN`](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/) ?**

---

More precisely, let's take an example of a RNN layer like this:
Input shape: (None, 250, 32)
Output shape: (None, 100)
**Given an input `x` of shape (250, 32), with which pseudo-code can I generate the output `y` of shape (100,), of course by using weights, etc.?**

Comment: Linked but not directly an answer: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-%E2%80%9CThe-number-of-units-in-the-LSTM-cell/answer/Shixian-Wen

Comment: https://render.githubusercontent.com/view/ipynb?commit=2bacadc7cc4c10c84048273e6a62bdc99d2048f8&enc_url=68747470733a2f2f7261772e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6e69636b6c617368616e73656e2f726e6e5f6c73746d5f66726f6d5f736372617463682f326261636164633763633463313063383430343832373365366136326264633939643230343866382f524e4e5f4c53544d5f66726f6d5f736372617463682e6970796e62&nwo=nicklashansen%2Frnn_lstm_from_scratch&path=RNN_LSTM_from_scratch.ipynb&repository_id=213749834&repository_type=Repository#Implement-the-forward-pass

Answer (score 1):

Simple RNN Cells follow this pattern:

```
Given the following data:
    input data:         X
    weights:            wx
    recursive weights:  wRec

Initialize initial hidden state to 0

For each state, one by one:
    Update new hidden state as: (Input data * weights) + (Hidden state + recursive weights)
```

In Python code:

```
def compute_states(X, wx, wRec):
    """
    Unfold the network and compute all state activations 
    given the input X, input weights (wx), and recursive weights 
    (wRec). Return the state activations in a matrix, the last 
    column S[:,-1] contains the final activations.
    """
    # Initialise a matrix that holds all states for all input sequences.
    # The initial state s_0 is set to 0, each of the others will depend from the previous.
    S = np.zeros((X.shape[0], X.shape[1]+1))

    # Compute each state k from the previous state ( S[:,k] ) and current input ( X[:,k] ), 
    # by use of the input weights (wx) and recursive weights (wRec).
    for k in range(0, X.shape[1]):
        S[:,k+1] = (X[:,k] * wx) + (S[:,k] * wRec)

    return S
```

This is a slightly more clear version of the code I found [here](https://peterroelants.github.io/posts/rnn-implementation-part01/).

Is this helpful for you?

Comment: LSTMs are much more complicated layers. The simple RNN layer has its `SimpleRNN()` class, you should substitute that to `LSTM()`. And yes, the function above is a forward pass that is calculated at each training iteration.

Comment: Sorry Leevo, I did a mistake, I meant this: `model = Sequential() model.add(Embedding(5000, 32, input_length=250)) model.add(SimpleRNN(100)) model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))`. What's the difference between SimpleRNNCell and SimpleRNN?

Comment: I think you need to apply an activiation function inside `compute_states`.

Comment: I also asked the same question once [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/54549/in-tensorflow-2-0-what-is-the-different-between-lstm-and-lstmcell-objects), it was related to `LSTM()` and `LSTMCell()` objects, but it's the same issue. One is the abstract class of the other. In practice, you always use the `SimpleRNN()` one, without the "`Cell`". Easy ;)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understood your comment on `compute_states`. Could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

In other words, what does the forward pass of a RNN look like. You read about using the inputs plus values from the previous node (here it will be prev_s)
First initialise the weights, than perform the foreward pass. I highlighted what you was looking for.

```
U = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (hidden_dim, T))
W = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (hidden_dim, hidden_dim))
V = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (output_dim, hidden_dim))


 for i in range(Y.shape[0]):
        x, y = X[i], Y[i]

        layers = []
        prev_s = np.zeros((hidden_dim, 1))
        dU = np.zeros(U.shape)
        dV = np.zeros(V.shape)
        dW = np.zeros(W.shape)

        dU_t = np.zeros(U.shape)
        dV_t = np.zeros(V.shape)
        dW_t = np.zeros(W.shape)

        dU_i = np.zeros(U.shape)
        dW_i = np.zeros(W.shape)

        # forward pass
        for t in range(T):
            new_input = np.zeros(x.shape)
            new_input[t] = x[t]
            mulu = np.dot(U, new_input)
            mulw = np.dot(W, prev_s)
            add = mulw + mulu
            s = sigmoid(add)
            ***mulv = np.dot(V, s)***
            layers.append({'s':s, 'prev_s':prev_s})
            prev_s = s
```

So the '***  ***' area can be roughly translated: mulv = np.dot(V, s) are the weights multiplied with the current state. (same as before, s==input_vector) but the difference is that the s will be calculated with weights from previous output and current input i.e.

```
mulu = np.dot(U, new_input)
mulw = np.dot(W, prev_s)
add = mulw + mulu
s = sigmoid(add)
```

Thats why we have 3 initial weights in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. Could you add your source, for future reference?

Comment: I have coded it long time ago on kaggle.